# gstreamer between two raspberry pis. Can't decode stream

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264

I am trying to setup gstreamer to send a video feed between two raspberry pis but I get an error.

-"Could not decode stream"
-"received buffer without first receiving caps"

This is the command I use to create the stream: `raspivid -t 0 -h 720 -w 1080 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! udpsink host=YOUR_RPI_IP_ADDRESS port=5000`

This is the one I use to try and watch the stream and the one that gives me the error: `gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! fbdevsink sync=false`

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I don't know `gstreamer` at all, but to my untrained eye it appears that you are transmitting via TCP whilst trying to receive via UDP. I guess your receiving command should use TCP. I may well be wrong - but noone else seems to have any ideas so maybe worth a try.

Comment: I had made a mistake when making this post. On the pi with the camera, the command I was using is udpsink, not the tcp one. I updated the post. I'll try to really go in depth and understand gstreamer I guess. It seems like something simple. Something about strings and the stream autodetecting the media or something like that from what I've been able to gather from the internet. I've seen some people specify the CAPS attribute and that may be where the solution lies.

Comment: I can't imagine it will work at all, let alone reliably, using UDP with 2MB frames.

Comment: That is the bitrate from the camera, it then gets compressed into h264, then streamed. At least from what I understand. That being said, What do you mean by what you said? I'm new to UDP vs TCP.

Comment: TCP is a reliable, in-sequence stream of bytes. UDP is unreliable, unsequenced and based on individual, independent packets - some of which may get lost, or duplicated or arrive out of order.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do need to use UDP as my project is very bandwidth restricted and TCP limits transfer speed with this bandwidth but it's nice to know the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by running the camera stream after. I had to start the receiving pipeline first. If you want to be able to connect anytime in any order, I think this is solved by adding the caps to the receiving pi. I didn't know what caps were when I first opened this thread.

Hope this helps if someone stumbles across it.